# MongoDB on a Windows 8 machine: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mongodb

I tried to create a cfg file as ucaiado has suggested but still got that error. Please help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTYKa.png

Comment: Who is "ucaiado" and why did he suggest you to create what kind of config file which is supposed to fix what problem?

Comment: @Philipp you don't know ucaiado? u out bro

Comment: @Philipp omg, how dare you? I cannot believe you don't know who is ucaiado.

Comment: Shame on me. How could I forget the legendary stackexchange user [ucaiado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3277875/ucaiado) who amassed a massive 36 reputation over just 6 months.

Comment: He *was* legendary back in the day.

Comment: oh man, you guys cracked me up~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Download MongoDB**

**2. Install MongoDB**

**3. Create the required folders:**

```
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\data\db"
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\logs"
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\etc"
```

NOTE: If the directories do not exist, mongod.exe will not start.

**4. Create a simple configuration file:**

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\logs\mongo.log
    logAppend: true
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1
    port: 27017
```

More info about how to create a configuration file: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

**5. Install MongoDB as a Windows Service (this way it will start automatically when you reboot your computer)**

Run cmd with administrator privilegies, and enter the following commands:

```
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\etc\mongodb.conf" --dbpath c:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\data\db --directoryperdb --install
```

**6. Start the MongoDB Windows Service**

```
net start MongoDB
```

**7. Connect to MongoDB via shell/cmd for testing**

```
C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\mongo.exe
```

NOTE: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/

**8. That's it! You are done. :)**

**9. Uninstall/remove the MongoDB Windows Service (if you messed up something)**

```
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
```

Comment: Can I say this is better write-up for what I found at **MongoDB** community site? :-)

Comment: Thank you @user3339918 I had this problem too, that's why i posted it here. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the log file you posted, you are closing MongoDB yourself using the Ctrl+C shortcut:

```
 Ctrl-C signal
 [consoleTerminate] got CTRL_C_EVENT, will terminate after current cmd ends
 [consoleTerminate] now exiting
```

Start `mongod`, leave the command prompt open, open a **new** command prompt, and run `mongo` from the second prompt.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. Do I have to start mongod and open a new command everytime?

Comment: @user3339918 Everytime you want to *do what*?

Comment: Do I need to type 
`C:\mongodb\bin>  mongod --config C:\mongodb\conf\mongod.cfg`
and `mongo` in separate command windows everytime?

Comment: @user3339918 Yes. Although there is a trick to start a program in a new window by using the `start` program. Type `start /?` for the complete syntax and ask on https://superuser.com when you need more help with using the windows command shell.